# Is there a library that adds xliff support to Spring i18n MessageSource?

Tags: spring-mvc, internationalization, xliff

Spring's ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource supports properties (key=value) format, and I can't seem to find a library that supports xliff format. Is there a library that adds the xliff support to Spring (that works with Thymeleaf)?

There's google closure soy view, but that is going to replace thymeleaf view that we are currently using, and not sure if soy works well with Spring web.

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: Looks like we'll need a different PropertiesPersister that supports xliff.

Comment: Did you ever find out more?